# Eclipse: comment entire code without it getting cut short by another comment

Tags: c++, eclipse, comments, block-comments

Say I have the following code (in C++, but that's probably not important to the question):

```
int main() {
    ....random code....
    /*This is a comment*/
    ....random code....
    return 0;
}
```

In eclipse, when I want to comment out the entire code by putting /* and */ before and after the code, the comment is cut short by the */ at the end of the "This is a comment" on line 3, so the rest of the code is left uncommented.

```
/*    //<--overall comment starts here
int main() {
    ....random code....
    /*This is a comment*/    //<--overall comment ends here
    ....random code....
    return 0;
}
*/  //<--overall comment SHOULD end here
```

Anyone know a way of getting around this problem, or do I just have to deal with it or use // comments...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way of having nested comments in C++. One solution (especially if you don't want to change lots of `/* */` to `//`) is to use the pre-processor, you can do something like

```
#ifdef SOME_RANDOM_SYMBOL

code that you want to comment here

#endif
```

Just make sure that `SOME_RANDOM_SYMBOL` is not somehow defined in your code.

As mentioned by @Caleb in the comment, you can also do

```
#if 0

code that you want to comment here

#endif
```

but using a symbol allows you to search for it.

Comment: Or just `#if 0 ... #endif`, but `SOME_RANDOM_SYMBOL` allows you to give it an easily searchable name for when you want to undo the change.